# Reference a javascript variable in a div flag HTML

Tags: html

I have some code using A login form and I need to reference a javascript variable inside a div. Here is the HTML.

```
    <div class="div"
    variable="Variable Here?" 
    </div>
```

Here is the javascript.

```
function setLoginFormVars(form) {
        localStorage.setItem('email', email = document.getElementById("email").value);
        localStorage.setItem('apikey', apikey = document.getElementById("apikey").value);
        window.location.href = 'miner.html';
      }
```

The javascript is in the file where the form is. The function `setLoginFormVars` Is run when the login button is clicked.

How would I specify that it is a variable and is it even possible to do what im asking.

Thank you.

Nyle

Comment: you should share the login JavaScript so that we can get a better understanding. Typically you would separate the JavaScript from the HTML for something like this. More than likely you wouldnt want inline JavaScript with your HTML.

Comment: added the javascript.

Comment: 'I need to reference a javascript variable inside a div' why would you have a javascript variable declared inside of an HTML div? can this variable be maintained within the javascript file?

Comment: Its to do with the coin-hive miner API. I am making a miner people can use. the reason I want to do this is because the miner requires the API key directly in the div.